# window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript

Такой вопрос: Есть у меня блок который на начале страницы идет display:none и так же есть кнопка которая стоит блоком, если я кликаю на кнопку то у меня открывается попап и если я кликну на сам попап то у меня должно перезапустить страницу через window.location.reload() и после показать первоначальный блок который был сначала когда зашёл на страницу display:none.
Реально ли решить такую задачу?

Comment: Да, реально решить такую задачу.

Comment: Читайте про localStorage

Comment: Плюсую @АлексейШиманский, такую задачу реально можно решить.

Answer (score 0):

ты можешь использовать `localStorage` для этого.

Тебе надо:

1. При открытии попапа сохранить какой-нибудь флаг в `localStorage`, который бы говорил о том, что попап был открыт
2. При загрузке страницы надо проверять есть ли этот флаг в `localStorage` и равен ли он `true`
3. Если он равен `true`, то добавлять скрытому блоку `display: block;`

Примерно так:

```js
// Эта функция должна вызываться при открытии попапа
const onPopupOpen = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("wasPopupOpened", "true");
  window.location.reload();
}

// Эта функция должна выполняться при загрузке страницы(например document.onload = onDocumentLoaded)
const onDocumentLoaded = () => {
  const wasPopupOpened = localStorage.getItem("wasPopupOpened");

  if(wasPopupOpened === "true"){
    document.querySelector("/** селектор скрытого блока */").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```